# How to unique id for dashboard tab in android?

Tags: java, android, xml

I have 3 tabs in my dashboard namely,

1. Invitation
2. Event
3. Groupchat

I am added all those tabs programmatically,In my layout code `id:tabContent` using for add all my tabs. My **Userdashboard.xml** code is below,

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-4dp"
        android:layout_weight="0" />

</LinearLayout>
```

In below code all tabs are  grouped as "tabHost". Now i  am need to set unique id for all the three tabs, but i dont know how to set unique id for that help me please thanks in advance.

```
public class UserDashBoardActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    private static final String TAB_1_TAG = "Invitation";
    private static final String TAB_2_TAG = "Event";
    private static final String TAB_3_TAG = "GroupChat";
    private FragmentTabHost tabHost;

    private Context context;
    private SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
    private Gson gson = new Gson();
    private Menu menu;

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        AppActivityStatus.setActivityStarted();
        AppActivityStatus.setActivityContext(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        AppActivityStatus.setActivityStoped();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onPause();
        AppActivityStatus.setActivityStarted();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        AppActivityStatus.setActivityStoped();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        this.menu=menu;
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_user_dash_board, menu);
        return true;
        //return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.user_dash_board);
        context = getApplicationContext();
        sharedpreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(Constants.SHARED_PREFERENCE_NAME,
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        // Get TabHost Reference
        tabHost= (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
        tabHost.setup(this, getSupportFragmentManager(), android.R.id.tabcontent);

       **Invitation,Event,Groupchat tabs** are added here    

    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec(TAB_1_TAG).setIndicator("Invitation"), InvitationFragment.class, null);
    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec(TAB_2_TAG).setIndicator("Event"), OccasionFragment.class, null);
    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec(TAB_3_TAG).setIndicator("GroupChat"), GroupChatFragment.class, null);

        //invitation tab highlighted by default
        tabHost.getTabWidget().setCurrentTab(0);
        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(0).setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Orange));
        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(1).setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.scandal));
        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(2).setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.scandal));


        //onTabChangedListener added for move one tab to others

        tabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onTabChanged(String arg0) {
                   setTabColor(tabHost);
            }
        });


    }
        if(tabHost.getCurrentTab()==0)
        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabHost.getCurrentTab()).setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Orange));//1st tab selected
        else if(tabHost.getCurrentTab()==1)
        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabHost.getCurrentTab()).setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Orange)); //2nd tab selected
        else if(tabHost.getCurrentTab()==2)
        tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(tabHost.getCurrentTab()).setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Orange)); //3rd tab selected
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();
        // noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.account_settings) {
            Intent userSettingIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ActivityUserSettings.class);
            userSettingIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(userSettingIntent);
            return true;
        }

        if (id == R.id.profile) {
            Intent profileIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ImageUploadActivity.class);
            profileIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(profileIntent);
            return true;
        }

        if(id == R.id.create_occasion){

            Intent occasionAct = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), OccasionActivity.class);
            // Clears History of Activity
            occasionAct.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(occasionAct);

        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The call to `tabHost.newTabSpec()` takes a String as tag. In your case these are `TAB_1_TAG`, `TAB_2_TAG`, `TAB_3_TAG`, so these are your unique IDs for each tab respectively.

You can identify the selected tab in `onTabChanged(String arg0)` here `arg0` is the name of the selected tag.

Furthermore you can use `tabHost.getCurrentTabTag()` to identify tabs by tag instead of `tabHost.getCurrentTab()` which is by tab position.